Rendering of code cell output in mkdocs in notebook
I am using mkdocs for my static website, but I get such rendering sometimes in my jupyter notebook. The output of the code cell is next to the code cell. I would like the output to be below the code cell.

If you need more info, do not hesitate.
Please find the content of mkdocs.yml:
site_name: Learning Site
site_dir: public

nav:
  - Home: index.md
  - Numerical Methods: 
    - Overview: numerical_methods/numerical_methods.md
    - Solving Ordinary Differential Equations:
        - Presentation of ODEs: numerical_methods/ode/ode.md
        - The forward Euler method: numerical_methods/ode/explicit_euler.ipynb
        - The forward Euler method: numerical_methods/ode/implicit_euler.ipynb
    - Finite Difference Method:
        - Presentation of FDM: numerical_methods/fdm/fdm.md
        - time-independent equations:
            - 1D: numerical_methods/fdm/1d.ipynb
            - 2D: numerical_methods/fdm/2d.ipynb
        - time-dependent equations:
            - 1D: numerical_methods/fdm/1d-time.ipynb
    - Finite Volume Method: 
        - time-dependent equations:
            - 1D: numerical_methods/fvm/1d-time.ipynb
            - 1D: numerical_methods/fvm/2d-time.ipynb
    #- Finite Element Method:
  - Donation: donation.md

theme: 
  name: material
  icon:
      logo: material/book

  language: en
  features:
    - navigation.tabs
    - navigation.tabs.sticky
    - content.code.annotate
  palette:
    # Palette toggle for light mode
    - scheme: default
      toggle:
        icon: material/brightness-7
        name: Switch to dark mode

    # Palette toggle for dark mode
    - scheme: slate
      toggle:
        icon: material/brightness-4
        name: Switch to light mode
  plugins:
    - typeset

markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.arithmatex:
      generic: true

extra_javascript:
  - javascripts/mathjax.js
  - https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6
  - https://unpkg.com/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js

plugins:
  - search
  - mkdocs-jupyter:
      include_source: True


Please postt he code as a text, not a screenshot.

The purpose of the photo is to show the rendering of the notebook. When editing the notebook, the output is below the code cell (every time). Do you mean the code within the code cell of the notebook? Or the notebook?
